# Trouble with windows persistent route

Tags: windows, static-routes

I have a laptop that is connected wirelessly to 192.168.1.0/24 network using DHCP 
and wired to 10.10.10.0/24 network static settings with NO DEFAULT GATEWAY set up.

The goal was to access to external addresses using the default gateway on the wireless network (192.168.1.1) and the internal network (10.10.10.0/24, 10.10.20.0/24 and so on... 10.10.60.0/24) using the wired NIC.
So I've added the following persistent routes:

```
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:

  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric

       10.10.60.0    255.255.255.0       10.10.10.1       1
       10.10.50.0    255.255.255.0       10.10.10.1       1
       10.10.40.0    255.255.255.0       10.10.10.1       1
       10.10.20.0    255.255.255.0       10.10.10.1       1
       10.10.30.0    255.255.255.0       10.10.10.1      11
       10.10.10.0    255.255.255.0       10.10.10.1       1

===========================================================================

The routing table is the following:
IPv4 Route Table

===========================================================================
Active Routes:

Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric

          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.110      2
       10.10.10.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       10.10.10.27    266
       10.10.10.0    255.255.255.0       10.10.10.1      10.10.10.27     11
      10.10.10.27  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.10.10.27    266
     10.10.10.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.10.10.27    266
       10.10.30.0    255.255.255.0       10.10.10.1      10.10.10.27     21
       10.10.50.0    255.255.255.0       10.10.10.1      10.10.10.27     11
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331

  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331

      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.110    257
    192.168.1.110  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.110    257
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.110    257
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.10.10.27    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.110    257

  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331

  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.10.10.27    266


  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.110    257
```

But, after all this the packets take the wrong way:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>tracert -d 10.10.60.1

Tracing route to 10.10.60.1 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     5 ms     3 ms     3 ms  192.168.1.1
==============================================
^C

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Why do the packets take the 192.168.1.1 way ?

Shouldn't packets go the persistent route (10.10.10.1 )?

Comment: Remove the extra routes to `10.10.10.0`. You are already on that network directly, no need to try to reach it via a gateway. It most probably messes the routing table up.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but even without that line the behaviour is the same:       C:\WINDOWS\system32>route print 10.10.60.0     IPv4 Route Table
Active Routes:
  None
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
       10.10.60.0    255.255.255.0       10.10.10.1       1
C:\WINDOWS\system32>tracert -d 10.10.60.1

Tracing route to 10.10.60.1 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     5 ms     3 ms     2 ms  192.168.1.1

Comment: You're testing with 10.10.60.x but I don't see that in the active routes list? I would remove the static route for 10.10.10.x, restart and try to get to the point where all the persistent routes are showing as active. Then test again

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart networking or enable/disable the adapters? You might need to restart the TCP stack to get the new routing stuff recognized. Just a thought.

Comment: Disabling and enabling both adapters did the trick! Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is followings

```
route add 10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 10.28.15.201 -p
```

in addition to above you should always add interface number like (if you are not planing to swap the interfaces later on)

```
route add 10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 10.28.15.201 -p IF 12
```

(interface list is shown in route print)

I just added gateway for both interfaces, windows gave me warning that there is gateway conflict, i just Said OK, and then added routs on specific interface
and it works for me .

here is what i have achieved with above mentioned route add

```
C:\Users\Administrator>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 23...00 25 90 f5 61 66 ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3
 21...00 25 90 f5 61 67 ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
 15...00 25 90 f5 61 69 ......Intel(R) I350 Gigabit Network Connection #4
 12...00 25 90 f5 61 68 ......Intel(R) I350 Gigabit Network Connection
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 16...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 17...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 18...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
 49...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   174.xx.xxx.xxx   174.xx.xxx.yyy    261
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      10.28.147.1      10.28.147.4    261
         10.0.0.0        255.0.0.0      10.28.147.1      10.28.147.4      6
      10.28.147.0  255.255.255.192         On-link       10.28.147.4    261
      10.28.147.4  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.28.147.4    261
     10.28.147.63  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.28.147.4    261
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
    174.xx.xx.zzz  255.255.255.248         On-link    174.xx.xxx.yyy    261
    174.xx.xxx.yyy  255.255.255.255         On-link    174.xx.xxx.yyy    261
    174.xx.xx.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    174.xx.xxx.yyy    261
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    174.xx.xxx.yyy    261
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.28.147.4    261
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    174.xx.xxx.yyy    261
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.28.147.4    261
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
         10.0.0.0        255.0.0.0      10.28.147.1       1
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   174.xx.xxx.xxx  Default
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   174.xx.xxx.xxx     256
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      10.28.147.1  Default
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      10.28.147.4  Default
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================

===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

C:\Users\Administrator>tracert -d 10.28.147.53

Tracing route to 10.28.147.53 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.28.147.53

Trace complete.

C:\Users\Administrator>
```